# Redux: Alternative way of clearing Object of Array

Tags: javascript, redux

I have a state that could look like this:

```
 [
  0: {
    "id": "8e9x23x2wto",
    "name": "test-player",
    "currentFrame": 1,
    "rolls": {
      "1": [1,3],
      "2": [1,6],
      "3": [1,6],
      "4": [3,8],
      "5": [4,5],
      "6": [7,6],
      "7": [8,1],
      "8": [5,2],
      "9": [2,1],
      "10": [1,1]
    },
    "totalWins": 0
  }
]
```

I am clearing the `rolls` Object and resetting `currentFrame` like so:

```
case RESET_GAME:
  return {
    ...state,
    players: state.players.map((player) => {
      return {
        ...player,
        currentFrame: 1,
        rolls: Object.assign(player.rolls, Object.values(player.rolls).map(() => []))
      }
    }),
  }
```

However, sometimes random Arrays within `rolls` don't get cleared - could be the second one, could be the last one...I have no idea way.

Is there any alternative way to clear `rolls` so that it only consists of empty Arrays or does someone have an explanation why that might happen? 
Any input is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure, but looking at this, I would wager that these problems are coming about due to mutations to the `player.rolls` object rather than creating a clean version of it.

Right now, your code with the objects is creating a new object and filling in that new object with keys/values from the old object. This maintains immutability of your objects rather than mutating the original object. React/Redux tends not to do well with mutable objects.

#### General examples

Mutable example:

```js
const x = {};
Object.assign(x, {'a': 1, 'b': 2});
// x is now {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

In this example, we took x, and we mutated it. Notice, it's a bit tricky here that we also used `const` with x, which just means that we cannot re-assign the "pointer" that x is, but we can still change the values that that pointer is pointing to. So saying

```js
const x = {};
x = 2; // Will not work
```

Immutable example:

```js
var x = {};
x = {...x, ...{'a': 1, 'b': 2}}; // assign x to a new object populated by the previous x and the new stuff
```

In this case, we did not mutate our x object, but instead assigned x to a new object that was populated using the keys/values from our old x object and the new object key/values we wanted to have in there (though in this case it's unnecessary as x doesn't have any key/values within it initially).

### Your code

```js
return { // not mutating
    ...state,
    players: state.players.map((player) => { // not mutating
      return { // not mutating
        ...player,
        currentFrame: 1,
        rolls: Object.assign( // mutating player.rolls rather than making a new rolls object.
          player.rolls, 
          Object.values(player.rolls).map(() => [])
        ) 
      }
    }),
  }
```

I'd recommend doing something like...

```js
return {
    ...state,
    players: state.players.map((player) => {
      return {
        ...player,
        currentFrame: 1,
        rolls: []
      }
    }),
  }
```

which is simpler, cleaner, and as you said, you're just clearing the whole `rolls` key anyways... unless I misunderstood?

See also [Object.assign's MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) where it states 
*The target object — what to apply the sources’ properties to, which is returned **after it is modified.*** (Bolding my own).

I can't think of many cases where you'd want to use Object.assign over the using the spread operator (the `{...{'a': 1}, ...{'b': 2}}` one).

### Edit

Looking this over again, I realize you want to remake the 10 entries in the `rolls` object and not lose them entirely.

I think a better solution would be to just make a fresh object with empty entries in it. i.e.

```js
return {
    ...state,
    players: state.players.map((player) => {
      return {
        ...player,
        currentFrame: 1,
        rolls: {
           "1": [0,0],
           "2": [0,0],
           "3": [0,0],
           "4": [0,0],
           "5": [0,0],
           "6": [0,0],
           "7": [0,0],
           "8": [0,0],
           "9": [0,0],
           "10": [0,0]
        }
      }
    }),
  }
```

I'm not sure why you use an object with numeric keys over a list, but yeah.

Comment: Thanks for your thorough explanation! Unfortunately, I need to keep the keys of  `rolls` and therefore only want to clear the associated Arrays.

Comment: Made an edit. I think you want to "remake" the keys of rolls, not keep them. Keeping them will lead to problems. But yeah, I re-read your code and understand it a bit better, I made a mistake in my initial answer. Hope that helps! And of course, glad to help!

Answer (score 2):

It's common to have:

1. `const initialState = {...}`
2. use it as initial state for your store, `createStore(myReducer, initialState)`
3. and use it in your reset action, `case RESET_GAME: return initialState`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. `state.players` is generated dynamically meaning the user can add players to it, so I am not sure how I could set an initial state. I need to keep `id` and `name` while clearing out `rolls`.

Comment: @suuuriam, you can (and should) use [combineReducers](https://redux.js.org/api/combinereducers) to separate your application's state into several parts where each "part" is managed by a separate reducer and separate initial state. This way you can easily reset the entire app state, a single part, or many parts - whatever your app needs.

Comment: I will -  I am quite new to Redux (obviously) so I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.fromEntries`

```
players: state.players.map((player) => {
      return {
        ...player,
        currentFrame: 1,
        rolls: Object.fromEntries( Object.keys(player.rolls).map((key)=>[key,[]]))
      }
    }
```

```js
let player = {
  rolls: {
    "1": [1, 3],
    "2": [1, 6],
    "3": [1, 6],
    "4": [3, 8],
    "5": [4, 5],
    "6": [7, 6],
    "7": [8, 1],
    "8": [5, 2],
    "9": [2, 1],
    "10": [1, 1]
  }
}
console.log(Object.fromEntries( Object.keys(player.rolls).map((key)=>[key,[]])))
```